# The login loop after changing nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, login

I'm trying to (freshly) install Ubuntu on my old machine (AMD 2800, 2 GB RAM), but end up in the login loop time after time. I tried it first with Ubuntu 16.04, and now installed 14.04, but the problem remains.

First it works, but I have problems with flickering boxes and extremely slow performance (although less slow with 14.04). Looks like a problem with my Nvidia driver (GeForce 6150 LE). With the help of [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) I resolved it, it seems, by `purge nvidia*`  and `install nvidia-367`. I think this works, because the system becomes stable now. However, I end up in the loop.

I read [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). The permissions of .Xauthority are -rw-------. But `chown` or `rm` does not change anything. Nor `chown .ICEauthority`. Nor `sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup` or `service lightdm restart`.

Then I tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, but this was broken off and I got the instruction to manually run `sudo dpkg –-configure -a` (although I don't know what I'm doing). This process ran until it came to nvidia.

```
Deleting module version 367.44
completely from the DKMS tree
–----------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-367-367.44 DKMS files...
First installation: checking all kernels…
Building only for 4.4.0-31-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-31-generic
```

And after that, everything stops.
After reset I get a message something like this:

```
No PSB or PCSI objects...
Make sure that Cool 'n Quiet is…
```

After another reset I come to the login screen again. But in the terminal, anything I do gives the same process as above. I tried to remove nvidia, but it ends in the same crash (after 'building intial module' etc.)

I've done several fresh installations, but end up in the same situation.

I will do a new installation now (16.04), but how can I change the driver and yet avoid the loop?

By the way, Ubuntu worked perfectly when I just tried it out from the installation USB.